# Problema na configuração do nginx

Tags: aplicação-web, nginx

Salve pessoal,
Estou com dificuldade nesta configuração:

```
local do arquivo: /etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf

#
# A virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#

server {
    listen 80; # porta
    server_name sitex.com.br www.sitex.com.br; # site

    access_log off; # logs de acesso
    error_log /var/log/nginx/sitex.com.br.error.log; # local dos logs

    root /var/www/vhosts/sitex.com.br/public; # local da pasta

    index .index.html index.php; # index da pagina

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)${
            expires max;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    location ~ \.(php|phtml)${
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location ~ /\. { deny all; }

}
```

Com este arquivo de configuração está me retornando um erro ao dar restart ao nginx:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
nginx: [emerg] directive "location" has no opening "{" in /etc/ngin/conf.d/virtual.conf:21
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

É a primeira vez que faço uso dele, daí não sei ao certo se esse código está correto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema graças a Ajudar do instrutor:
o erro estava apenas onde:

> location ~* .(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)${

e

> location ~ .(php|phtml)${

colocava um espaço entre $ e {:

> location ~* .(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
>
> location ~ .(php|phtml)$ {

```
local do arquivo: /etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf

#
# A virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#

server {
listen 80; # porta
server_name sitex.com.br www.sitex.com.br; # site

access_log off; # logs de acesso
error_log /var/log/nginx/sitex.com.br.error.log; # local dos logs

root /var/www/vhosts/sitex.com.br/public; # local da pasta

index .index.html index.php; # index da pagina

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}

location ~ \.(php|phtml)$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

location ~ /\. { deny all; }

}
```

Solucionado.
Fica a dica para quem passar pelo mesmo problema.
Valeu.